Extracting executable with tar
I am downloading mysql client into a mysql-client.tar.gz folder with the following command:
$ curl -fL -o mysql-client.tar.gz https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-8.4/mysql-8.4.0-linux-glibc2.28-x86_64.tar.xz

Next, I would like to unpack it and copy the executable mysql to /usr/local/bin:
$ tar xf mysql-client.tar.gz 
$ cd mysql-8.4.0-linux-glibc2.28-x86_64/bin
$ cp mysql /usr/local/bin
$ rm -f ~/mysql-client.tar.gz
$ chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/mysql

Is there a more elegant/clean way of doing it?

Is there a more elegant/clean way of doing it? The most clean way is using your distros package manager.

@tkausl Unfortunately I cannot use "yum install mysql". I need to use the way I described in my question

And what kind of "more elegant" are you looking for?

@tkausl I was looking for a way to directly extract an executable with 'tar'

Ultimately you could download and extract without a temporary file:
curl -L https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-8.4/mysql-8.4.0-linux-glibc2.28-x86_64.tar.xz | 
    tar -Jx -C /usr/local/bin --strip-components=2 mysql-8.4.0-linux-glibc2.28-x86_64/bin/mysql


thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for. However, I get the error "tar: mysql: Cannot open: Permission denied" when I run it

any idea how to fix it? thank you

@anechkayf: You need write permission in directory /usr/local/bin.
